Need help in Censoring for Survival Analysis?
I have data of employees who joined in different months in last 3 years, assume it as a x month and out of those people people left in different months, assume this as y months.
I have total 23000 employees out of this 3000 people left till today. I have seen some articles referred for censoring in different ways,
1=death and 0=Alive
1=Alive and 2=Death
I'm really confused with which one to use, not able to figure out the logical reasoning behind these censoring.

It makes no difference at all, you only need to make sure that whatever algorithm or routine you're using 'knows' which observations are censored and which aren't. For example, in SAS you would write model time*event(X) where X indicates the value(s) of your event code that corresponds to censoring. The actual value(s) used is just a convention. R's Surv will check if your event code contains 2 & will use 1 for censoring if so, or assume 0/1 (0=censored) otherwise.

It's critical to use the coding assumed by your software. I recall that MATLAB, at least as some time in the past, expected coding with censored=1 so that an event was coded as 0.
